# Apple Push Notifications working in NodeJS but not with PHP on same server

Tags: php, node.js, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

Here is my NodeJS code , which is working totally fine.

```
var options = {
    //production
    "cert": readCredentialsFile(cert_file),
    "key":  readCredentialsFile(cert_key_file),
    "production" : production_val,
    "passphrase": "mypassphrase",
    "gateway": gateway_val,
    "port": 2195,
    "enhanced": true,
    "cacheLength": 5,
    "retryLimit":-1
};

options.errorCallback = apnError;

var feedBackOptions = {
    "cert": readCredentialsFile(cert_file),
    "key":  readCredentialsFile(cert_key_file),
    "passphrase": "mypassphrase",
    "production" : production_val,
    "batchFeedback": true,
    "interval": 300
};

var apnConnection, feedback;


module.exports = {

    initAPN : function(){
       try {
          apnConnection = new apn.Connection(options);

          feedback = new apn.Feedback(feedBackOptions);
          feedback.on("feedback", function (devices) {
            devices.forEach(function (item) {
              //TODO Do something with item.device and item.time;
            });
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
    },
    sendIOSNotification : function (device_token,message,params){
        var myDevice, note;
        try{

        console.log("iOS device_token ", device_token);
            var randomID = require("random-id");
            var payloadMultiCast = {
              "data": {
                "id": randomID(),
                "status": params.notification_type,
                "title": message,
                "body": params,
                "message": message
              }
            };


            myDevice = new apn.Device(device_token);
            note = new apn.Notification();

            note.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600; // Expires 1 hour from now.
            note.badge = 1;
            note.sound = "ping.aiff";
            note.alert = message;
            note.payload = payloadMultiCast;

            console.log("iOS Notification ", note);

            if(apnConnection) {
              apnConnection.pushNotification(note, myDevice);
              console.log("iOS res "+ device_token+":::"+JSON.stringify(apnConnection));
            }else{
              console.log("NO APNS CONNECTION");
            }
        }catch(err){
            console.log("error:-"+err);

        }

  }
}
```

And below is my php code , which is not working with same "pem" file and same credentials:-

```
$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, $options);
$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $error, $errorString, 60000, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

if (!$apns)
    $errrrr = json_encode(error_get_last());
echo("Failed to connect 11amarnew: $err $errstr $errrrr" . PHP_EOL);

$apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $dev)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);
fclose($apns);


$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $file);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

$err = ""; $errstr = "";

$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', 
    $err, 
    $errstr, 
    600000, 
    STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, 
    $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    $errrrr = json_encode(error_get_last());
exit("Failed to connect amarnew: $err $errstr $errrrr" . PHP_EOL);

//echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$message = "Hello Moto!!";

$body['aps'] = array(
    'badge' => +1,
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
);

$payload = json_encode($body);

$deviceToken = "ed3d13a56a92027acbb9805bfa5f9a3d6da4fdcf24a57b375bfb638259e9d31c";

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $dev) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); die();
if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered amar'.$message. PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

The error i am getting is -

```
Failed to connect amarnew: 0 {"type":2,"message":"stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl:\/\/gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error)","file":"\/var\/www\/html\/push.php","line":42}
```

FYI , I have allowed 2195 , 2196 ports also on my sever for PHP , NodeJS doesn't need port to be opened.

Then what is issue that causing not working in PHP and working in NodeJS, finally i have to use the php only hence i need to solve the issue.

Thanks,

Comment: are you getting any errors from APN?

Comment: @RaduDiță : I have updated post with error message.

Comment: are you sure you have outbound traffic enabled for those ports? when you enable ports you usually enable inbound traffic